# DirectX 11 и FBX SDK - некорректное отображение 3D модели

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, fbx

Изучаю Direct3D 11. Решил написать загрузку 3D моделей с помощью FBX SDK, но при загрузке какой либо модели (в данном случае куб) - она отображается неправильно (смотрите скриншот).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот файл FbxLoader.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <fbxsdk.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <xnamath.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct VertexBuffer {
    XMFLOAT3 Pos;
};
struct IndexBuffer {
    unsigned short index;
};
class FBXLoader {
private:
    FbxManager * g_pFbxSdkManager = nullptr;

public:
    FBXLoader();

    ~FBXLoader();

    // Функция загрузки 3D модели формата FBX.
    HRESULT LoadFBX(LPCSTR path, VertexBuffer* vertexBuffer, IndexBuffer* IndexBuffer);

};
```

Вот FbxLoader.cpp

```
#include "FbxLoader.h"

FBXLoader::FBXLoader()
{
}

FBXLoader::~FBXLoader()
{
}

HRESULT FBXLoader::LoadFBX(LPCSTR path, VertexBuffer* vertexBuffer, IndexBuffer* indexBuffer)
{
    if (g_pFbxSdkManager == nullptr)
    {
        g_pFbxSdkManager = FbxManager::Create();

        FbxIOSettings* pIOsettings = FbxIOSettings::Create(g_pFbxSdkManager, IOSROOT);
        g_pFbxSdkManager->SetIOSettings(pIOsettings);
    }

    FbxImporter* pImporter = FbxImporter::Create(g_pFbxSdkManager, "");
    FbxScene* pFbxScene = FbxScene::Create(g_pFbxSdkManager, "");

    bool bSuccess = pImporter->Initialize(path, -1, g_pFbxSdkManager->GetIOSettings());
    if (!bSuccess) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Не удалось загрузить 3D модель.", "Ошибка", MB_ICONERROR);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    bSuccess = pImporter->Import(pFbxScene);
    if (!bSuccess) return E_FAIL;

    pImporter->Destroy();
    FbxNode* pFbxRootNode = pFbxScene->GetRootNode();

    if (pFbxRootNode)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pFbxRootNode->GetChildCount(); i++)
        {
            FbxNode* pFbxChildNode = pFbxRootNode->GetChild(i);

            if (pFbxChildNode->GetNodeAttribute() == NULL)
                continue;

            FbxNodeAttribute::EType AttributeType = pFbxChildNode->GetNodeAttribute()->GetAttributeType();

            if (AttributeType != FbxNodeAttribute::eMesh)
                continue;

            FbxMesh* pMesh = (FbxMesh*)pFbxChildNode->GetNodeAttribute();

            FbxVector4* pVertices = pMesh->GetControlPoints();

            for (int j = 0; j < pMesh->GetPolygonCount(); j++)
            {
                int iNumVertices = pMesh->GetPolygonSize(j);
                assert(iNumVertices == 3);

                for (int k = 0; k < iNumVertices; k++) {
                    indexBuffer[j].index = pMesh->GetPolygonVertex(j, k);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < pMesh->GetControlPointsCount(); i++)
            {
                FbxVector4 vec;
                vec = pMesh->GetControlPointAt(i);

                vertexBuffer[i].Pos.x = vec.mData[0];
                vertexBuffer[i].Pos.y = vec.mData[1];
                vertexBuffer[i].Pos.z = vec.mData[2];
            }
        }
    }
    return S_OK;
}
```

Вот Main.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <xnamath.h>
#include "FbxLoader.h"
#include "Debug.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

VertexBuffer vertices[8];
IndexBuffer indices[36];

struct ConstantBuffer
{
    XMMATRIX mWorld;
    XMMATRIX mView;
    XMMATRIX mProjection;
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Global Variables
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HINSTANCE               g_hInst = NULL;
HWND                    g_hWnd = NULL;
D3D_DRIVER_TYPE         g_driverType = D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_NULL;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL       g_featureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;
ID3D11Device*           g_pd3dDevice = NULL;
ID3D11DeviceContext*    g_pImmediateContext = NULL;
IDXGISwapChain*         g_pSwapChain = NULL;
ID3D11RenderTargetView* g_pRenderTargetView = NULL;
ID3D11VertexShader*     g_pVertexShader = NULL;
ID3D11PixelShader*      g_pPixelShader = NULL;
ID3D11InputLayout*      g_pVertexLayout = NULL;
ID3D11Buffer*           g_pVertexBuffer = NULL;
ID3D11Buffer*           g_pIndexBuffer = NULL;
ID3D11Buffer*           g_pConstantBuffer = NULL;
XMMATRIX                g_World;
XMMATRIX                g_View;
XMMATRIX                g_Projection;
FBXLoader fbxLoader;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Forward declarations
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow);
HRESULT InitDevice();
void CleanupDevice();
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void Render();


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Entry point to the program. Initializes everything and goes into a message processing 
// loop. Idle time is used to render the scene.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    if (FAILED(InitWindow(hInstance, nCmdShow)))
        return 0;

    if (FAILED(InitDevice()))
    {
        CleanupDevice();
        return 0;
    }

    // Main message loop
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else
        {
            Render();
        }
    }

    CleanupDevice();

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Register class and create window
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register class
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, (LPCTSTR)"IDI_TUTORIAL1");
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = "TutorialWindowClass";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, (LPCTSTR)"IDI_TUTORIAL1");
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return E_FAIL;

    // Create window
    g_hInst = hInstance;
    RECT rc = { 0, 0, 640, 480 };
    AdjustWindowRect(&rc, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);
    g_hWnd = CreateWindow("TutorialWindowClass", "GameEngine a1.0", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, NULL, NULL, hInstance,
        NULL);
    if (!g_hWnd)
        return E_FAIL;

    ShowWindow(g_hWnd, nCmdShow);

    return S_OK;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Helper for compiling shaders with D3DX11
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT CompileShaderFromFile(WCHAR* szFileName, LPCSTR szEntryPoint, LPCSTR szShaderModel, ID3DBlob** ppBlobOut)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    DWORD dwShaderFlags = D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS;
#if defined( DEBUG ) || defined( _DEBUG )
    // Set the D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG flag to embed debug information in the shaders.
    // Setting this flag improves the shader debugging experience, but still allows 
    // the shaders to be optimized and to run exactly the way they will run in 
    // the release configuration of this program.
    dwShaderFlags |= D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG;
#endif

    ID3DBlob* pErrorBlob;
    hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile((LPCSTR)szFileName, NULL, NULL, szEntryPoint, szShaderModel,
        dwShaderFlags, 0, NULL, ppBlobOut, &pErrorBlob, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        if (pErrorBlob != NULL)
            OutputDebugStringA((char*)pErrorBlob->GetBufferPointer());
        if (pErrorBlob) pErrorBlob->Release();
        return hr;
    }
    if (pErrorBlob) pErrorBlob->Release();

    return S_OK;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create Direct3D device and swap chain
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitDevice()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(g_hWnd, &rc);
    UINT width = rc.right - rc.left;
    UINT height = rc.bottom - rc.top;

    UINT createDeviceFlags = 0;
#ifdef _DEBUG
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverTypes[] =
    {
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE,
    };
    UINT numDriverTypes = ARRAYSIZE(driverTypes);

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    };
    UINT numFeatureLevels = ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels);

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
    ZeroMemory(&sd, sizeof(sd));
    sd.BufferCount = 1;
    sd.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    sd.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sd.OutputWindow = g_hWnd;
    sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    sd.Windowed = TRUE;

    for (UINT driverTypeIndex = 0; driverTypeIndex < numDriverTypes; driverTypeIndex++)
    {
        g_driverType = driverTypes[driverTypeIndex];
        hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, g_driverType, NULL, createDeviceFlags, featureLevels, numFeatureLevels,
            D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &sd, &g_pSwapChain, &g_pd3dDevice, &g_featureLevel, &g_pImmediateContext);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            break;
    }
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    // Create a render target view
    ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBuffer = NULL;
    hr = g_pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &g_pRenderTargetView);
    pBackBuffer->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    g_pImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &g_pRenderTargetView, NULL);

    // Setup the viewport
    D3D11_VIEWPORT vp;
    vp.Width = (FLOAT)width;
    vp.Height = (FLOAT)height;
    vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    vp.TopLeftX = 0;
    vp.TopLeftY = 0;
    g_pImmediateContext->RSSetViewports(1, &vp);

    // Compile the vertex shader
    ID3DBlob* pVSBlob = NULL;
    hr = CompileShaderFromFile((WCHAR*)"shaders/shader.fx", "VS", "vs_4_0", &pVSBlob);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            "The FX file cannot be compiled.  Please run this executable from the directory that contains the FX file.", "Error", MB_OK);
        return hr;
    }

    // Create the vertex shader
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateVertexShader(pVSBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pVSBlob->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &g_pVertexShader);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        pVSBlob->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    // Define the input layout
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
    {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    };
    UINT numElements = ARRAYSIZE(layout);

    // Create the input layout
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(layout, numElements, pVSBlob->GetBufferPointer(),
        pVSBlob->GetBufferSize(), &g_pVertexLayout);
    pVSBlob->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    // Set the input layout
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetInputLayout(g_pVertexLayout);

    // Compile the pixel shader
    ID3DBlob* pPSBlob = NULL;
    hr = CompileShaderFromFile((WCHAR*)"shaders/shader.fx", "PS", "ps_4_0", &pPSBlob);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            "The FX file cannot be compiled.  Please run this executable from the directory that contains the FX file.", "Error", MB_OK);
        return hr;
    }

    // Create the pixel shader
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreatePixelShader(pPSBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pPSBlob->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &g_pPixelShader);
    pPSBlob->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;


    fbxLoader.LoadFBX("models/cube.FBX", vertices, indices);
    Print(sizeof(vertices));
    Print("\n");
    Print(sizeof(indices));
    Print("\n");

    // Create vertex buffer
    /*SimpleVertex vertices[] =
    {
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f)},
    { XMFLOAT3(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f)},
    { XMFLOAT3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) },
    { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)},
    { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f)},
    { XMFLOAT3(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f)},
    { XMFLOAT3(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)},
    { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)},
    };*/
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(VertexBuffer) * 8;
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
    ZeroMemory(&InitData, sizeof(InitData));
    InitData.pSysMem = vertices;
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bd, &InitData, &g_pVertexBuffer);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    // Set vertex buffer
    UINT stride = sizeof(VertexBuffer);
    UINT offset = 0;
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &g_pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

    // Create index buffer
    /*WORD indices[] =
    {
        3,1,0,
        2,1,3,

        0,5,4,
        1,5,0,

        3,4,7,
        0,4,3,

        1,6,5,
        2,6,1,

        2,7,6,
        3,7,2,

        6,4,5,
        7,4,6,
    };*/
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(WORD) * 36;        // 36 vertices needed for 12 triangles in a triangle list
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    InitData.pSysMem = indices;
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bd, &InitData, &g_pIndexBuffer);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    // Set index buffer
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer(g_pIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0);

    // Set primitive topology
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    // Create the constant buffer
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(ConstantBuffer);
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &g_pConstantBuffer);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    // Initialize the world matrix
    g_World = XMMatrixIdentity();

    // Initialize the view matrix
    XMVECTOR Eye = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f);
    XMVECTOR At = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    XMVECTOR Up = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    g_View = XMMatrixLookAtLH(Eye, At, Up);

    // Initialize the projection matrix
    g_Projection = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(XM_PIDIV2, width / (FLOAT)height, 0.01f, 100.0f);

    return S_OK;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Clean up the objects we've created
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CleanupDevice()
{
    if (g_pImmediateContext) g_pImmediateContext->ClearState();

    if (g_pConstantBuffer) g_pConstantBuffer->Release();
    if (g_pVertexBuffer) g_pVertexBuffer->Release();
    if (g_pIndexBuffer) g_pIndexBuffer->Release();
    if (g_pVertexLayout) g_pVertexLayout->Release();
    if (g_pVertexShader) g_pVertexShader->Release();
    if (g_pPixelShader) g_pPixelShader->Release();
    if (g_pRenderTargetView) g_pRenderTargetView->Release();
    if (g_pSwapChain) g_pSwapChain->Release();
    if (g_pImmediateContext) g_pImmediateContext->Release();
    if (g_pd3dDevice) g_pd3dDevice->Release();
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Called every time the application receives a message
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Render a frame
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Render()
{
    // Update our time
    static float t = 0.0f;
    if (g_driverType == D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE)
    {
        t += (float)XM_PI * 0.0125f;
    }
    else
    {
        static DWORD dwTimeStart = 0;
        DWORD dwTimeCur = GetTickCount();
        if (dwTimeStart == 0)
            dwTimeStart = dwTimeCur;
        t = (dwTimeCur - dwTimeStart) / 1000.0f;
    }

    //
    // Animate the cube
    //
    g_World = XMMatrixRotationY(t);

    //
    // Clear the back buffer
    //
    float ClearColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.125f, 0.3f, 1.0f }; // red,green,blue,alpha
    g_pImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView(g_pRenderTargetView, ClearColor);

    //
    // Update variables
    //
    ConstantBuffer cb;
    cb.mWorld = XMMatrixTranspose(g_World);
    cb.mView = XMMatrixTranspose(g_View);
    cb.mProjection = XMMatrixTranspose(g_Projection);
    g_pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource(g_pConstantBuffer, 0, NULL, &cb, 0, 0);

    //
    // Renders a triangle
    //
    g_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader(g_pVertexShader, NULL, 0);
    g_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &g_pConstantBuffer);
    g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader(g_pPixelShader, NULL, 0);
    g_pImmediateContext->DrawIndexed(36, 0, 0);        // 36 vertices needed for 12 triangles in a triangle list

                                                       //
                                                       // Present our back buffer to our front buffer
                                                       //
    g_pSwapChain->Present(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Стоит проверить, что там действительно прочиталось 8 вершин и 36 индексов. А то вдруг там не список треугольников, а список смежных треугольников.

Comment: Проверил - 8 вершин (pMesh->GetControlPointsCount()). А вот как узнать количество индексов - не знаю.

Comment: Надо при присваивании нового индекса увеличивать счетчик. А то сейчас счетчик почему-то отсчитывает полигоны и на каждой итерации `for (int k = 0; k < iNumVertices; k++) {` переписывает один и тот же индекс.

Comment: 'for (int j = 0; j < pMesh->GetPolygonCount(); j++)' - счетчик полигонов. 'int iNumVertices = pMesh->GetPolygonSize(j);' - убеждаемся, что на один полигон приходится по 3 вершины.  indexBuffer[j].index = pMesh->GetPolygonVertex(j, k); - присваивание индекса. (j - это номер полигона, k - вершина на полигоне). Вот ссылка на рисунок - https://pastenow.ru/9335a52241381dac1a9d8daa6f39fd00

Comment: Вот то-то и оно. k - номер вершины в полигоне от нуля до iNumVertices, а присваивается одному и тому же `indexBuffer[j]`, затирая на каждой итерации предыдущее значение.

Comment: Как тогда присваивать нормальное значение индексам? Пробовал `indexBuffer[k]`, но без толку.

Comment: Заведите отдельный счетчик `index_index` и увеличивайте его после каждого присваивания.

Comment: Я только-что так и сделал, треугольников стало больше рисоваться, но все-равно куб не идеален. Сейчас буду разбираться с вершинами. Вот скрин - https://pastenow.ru/3T2A3

Comment: А индексов-то 36 прочиталось? А то может быть там список смежных треугольников

Comment: Индексов 36, я все провел. Вот индексы: `0 1 2 
2 1 3 

2 3 4 
4 3 5 

4 5 6 
6 5 7 

6 7 0 
0 7 1 

1 7 3 
3 7 5 

6 0 4 
4 0 2 `. Вот вершины - `X: -1 Y: -1 Z: 1
X: 1 Y: -1 Z: 1
X: -1 Y: 1 Z: 1
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 1
X: -1 Y: 1 Z: -1
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: -1
X: -1 Y: -1 Z: -1
X: 1 Y: -1 Z: -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему!
Просто вместо создания индексного буффера

`struct IndexBuffer {
    unsigned int index;
};`

я решил написать обычный WORD: 
`WORD indices[36];`. И всё заработало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но у меня есть другой вопрос: как я могу загрузить нормали вершин?